# No matching function to call to (string error)

Tags: c++

I was checking my code and ran into a really frustrating problem.

I made 3 files PersonalPizza.h PersonalPizzaTest.cpp and PersonalPizza.cpp

The errors i get is `[Error] no matching function for call to 'PersonalPizza::setCustomerName(std::string&)'`

and also `[Error] 'class PersonalPizza' has no member named 'getCustomerName'`

Here is my code if someone can help id greatly appreciate it. This is for my final project and I cant get it to work with how much hard i try. Also sorry for my english I am not a native speaker and have grammatical errors.

PersonalPizza.h

```
#ifndef PERSONALPIZZA_H
#define PERSONALPIZZA_H
#include <string>


class PersonalPizza
{
    public:
        PersonalPizza();
        PersonalPizza(double, double, double);

        bool setBasePizzaPrice(double);
        bool setSingleTopPrice(double);
        bool setNumTops(int);
        bool setTaxRate(double);
        bool setCustomerName(string);

        double getBasePizzaPrice()const;
        double getSingleTopPrice()const;
        int getNumTops()const;
        double getTaxRate()const;
        string getCustomerName()const;

        double calcSubtotal()const;
        double calcTax()const;
        double calcTotal()const;

    private:
        double basePizzaPrice;
        double singleTopPrice;
        int numTops;
        double taxRate;
        string customerName;
};

#endif // PERSONALPIZZA_H
```

PersonalPizzaTest.cpp

```
#include "PersonalPizza.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string storeName = "Pete’s Personal Pizzas";
    string toppingNames[7] = {"No Toppings"};
    char selection;
    string petesCustomerName;
    int petesNumOfToppings;

    PersonalPizza petes(0.095, 6.99, 1.09); //tax rate, base pizza rate and single topping price

    do
    {
        cout << "PERSONAL PIZZA INVOICE GENERATOR\n"

            << "-----------------------------------\n"

            << "a) Generate an Invoice\n"

            << "q) Quit\n";

        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 'a' || selection == 'A')
        {
            cout << "Please, enter your name: \n";
            cin >> petesCustomerName;
            while(!petes.setCustomerName(petesCustomerName))
            {
                cout << "Invalid name. Please enter your name again: \n";
                cin >> petesCustomerName;
            }

            cout << "Please, enter how many toppings you would like on your pizza: \n";
            cin >> petesNumOfToppings;
            while(!petes.setNumTops(petesNumOfToppings))
            {
                cout << "Invalid number. Please enter the number of toppings again: \n";
                cin >> petesNumOfToppings;
            }

            if(petesNumOfToppings > 0)
            {
                cout <<"Please write the toppings you want on your pizza: \n";
                for(int i = 0; i < petesNumOfToppings; i++)
                {
                    cout<< "Topping #" + i;
                    cin >> toppingNames[i];
                }
            }

            cout << "PERSONAL PIZZA INVOICE – Pete’s Personal Pizza" << endl
                 << "Customer: " << petes.getCustomerName() << endl
                 << fixed << setprecision(2)
                 << "----------------------------------------------" << endl
                 << "NUMBER TOPPINGS: " << setw(10) <<petes.getNumTops() << endl
                 << "Toppings: " << setw(10) << toppingNames << endl
                 << "SUBTOTAL:     "  << setw(10) << petes.calcSubtotal() << endl
                 << "TAX:          " << setw(10) << petes.calcTax() << endl
                 << "              -------" << endl
                 << "TOTAL         " setw(10) << petes.calcTotal() << endl;
        }
        else if (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q' && selection != 'a' && selection != 'A')
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection,\n";
        }
    }while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');

    if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q')
    {
        cout << "Thank you for using our program.\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

and lastly PersonalPizza.cpp

```
#include "PersonalPizza.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

PersonalPizza::PersonalPizza()
{
    basePizzaPrice = 7.99;
    singleTopPrice = 0.98;
    numTops = 0;
    taxRate = 0.075;
    customerName = "No Name";
}

PersonalPizza::PersonalPizza(double ttr, double tbpp, double stp)
{
    numTops = 0;
    customerName = "No Name";

    if(tbpp > 0)
    {
        basePizzaPrice = tbpp;
    }
    else
    {
        basePizzaPrice = 0;
    }

    if(singleTopPrice > 0)
    {
        singleTopPrice = stp;
    }
    else
    {
        singleTopPrice = 0;
    }
    if(ttr >= 0 && ttr <= 1)
    {
        taxRate = ttr;
    }
    else
    {
        taxRate = 0;
    }
}

bool PersonalPizza::setBasePizzaPrice(double price)
{
    bool validData;
    if(price > 0)
    {
        basePizzaPrice = price;
        validData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}

bool PersonalPizza::setSingleTopPrice(double price)
{
    bool validData;
    if(price > 0)
    {
        singleTopPrice = price;
        validData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}

bool PersonalPizza::setNumTops(int num)
{
    bool validData;
    if(num >= 0 && num <=7)
    {
        numTops = num;
        validData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}

bool PersonalPizza::setTaxRate(double num)
{
    bool validData;
    if(num >= 0 && num <= 1)
    {
        taxRate = num;
        validData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}

bool PersonalPizza::setCustomerName(string name)
{
    bool validData;
    if(name.length > 2)
    {
        customerName = name;
        validData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}

double PersonalPizza::getBasePizzaPrice()const
{
    return basePizzaPrice;
}

double PersonalPizza::getSingleTopPrice()const
{
    return singleTopPrice;
}

int PersonalPizza::getNumTops()const
{
    return numTops;
}

double PersonalPizza::getTaxRate()const
{
    return taxRate;
}
string PersonalPizza::getCustomerName()const
{
    return customerName;
}

double PersonalPizza::calcSubtotal()const
{
    return basePizzaPrice + (numTops * singleTopPrice);
}

double PersonalPizza::calcTax()const
{
    return calcSubtotal() * taxRate;
}

double PersonalPizza::calcTotal()const
{
    return calcSubtotal() + calcTax();
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings and errors.  You did not mention how you compiled your code, which is probably where the problem is (but hard to say for sure).

Comment: The error message will probably contain a file name and line number which helps you locate the problem.